# What are the best practices of using branch under review (before merge into main) in a feature branch?

Tags: git

**Clarification:**

My intention was more like this:

```
          hotfix (Branch A) --- PR into dev under review
         /                            V
 1---2---3---4-----------------------dev (or main)
   \
     x---y---z feature (Branch B)
```

So eventually branches A and B get merged into dev (main) branch. But Branch A is not merged yet, so the hotfix is not final.

This Q is more about git methodology (#3):

1. get the hotfix on-the-fly from Branch A into B and later update my code if the fix changes
2. wait for the PR and merge to get final fix
3. what are the other options?

**Original Q below:**

Branch A has a hot fix in PR under review.
Branch B development is blocked by that fix (needed to continue development and/or compile).

As a background, the fix needed by branch B is in a different branch since it is independent fix not related specifically to feature in branch B but B depends on it.

The problem I can see is that if I cherry pick or merge the fix in branch A into branch B - I face potential issues down the road in case the review (and the fix) on branch A is rejected or changes are required. While branch B development assumed these changes as done and build on top of them.

One solution would be to stop development until the review on Branch A is complete and the fix merged into master. But that would delay development on branch B. Any other/better approach in this situation?

Comment: You should rebase branch B on branch A (possibly more than once if branch A is modified).

Comment: Cherry pick the fix commit onto B. If the fix changes, cherry pick the new fix commit onto B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your branch is linear and doesn't have any new merge commits on it, then I agree with [blami's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73589349/184546). The only tweak I would make is I would always use the *fancy* rebase version with the `--onto` flag. In this way you don't need to care about whether A is simply updated with more commits (where regular rebase would work), or if A is re-written (where *fancy* rebase is needed).

For example, if you have 2 new linear commits on `branch_b`, you can just use this:

```
git fetch
git rebase branch_b~2 branch_b --onto origin/branch_a
```

This works in the general case, and you can do it now, and anytime `branch_a` changes. Finally, when `branch_a` is completed into `master`, then you would rewrite your branch one last time like this:

```
git fetch
git rebase branch_b~2 branch_b --onto origin/master
```

After that you can go back to using regular rebase until you complete `branch_b` into `master`:

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master branch_b
```

Note with a regular rebase you can leave off the last argument of `branch_b` if it's already checked out.

Obviously, change the `~2` in all of the above commands to however many new commits are on `branch_b` at the time you perform the rebase.

**Side Note:** using these advanced commands is easy once you get the hang of it, but it requires using the command line and having a good understanding of what you're doing. It may not be the case that everyone can easily follow this method and I wouldn't recommend asking a large number of users to do it regularly. This is the reason that force pushing shared branches is frowned upon, since it requires everyone to be informed about the state of the branches, and understand how to use these types of commands. Most of the time, I would actually just recommend waiting until feature A is complete before starting on feature B, to avoid requiring this complexity.

Comment: Right, so no other option besides keeping up to date with the hotfix while it merges (and potentially rewriting dependent code in feature branch) or waiting for it to merge?

Comment: @AlexanderShapiro I think those are the 2 best options: either keep updating your code every time the hotfix changes, as I described here, or just wait to do anything until the hotfix is finalized. What other option could there be? I suppose you could complete your PR first and lock in whatever version of the hotfix you were using, and then it's up to the hotfix developers to pick up the pieces on their end. But, that seems sort of irresponsible to do that without the hotfix folks agreeing to it. (What if the hotfix had a major bug that they were still working on?)

Answer (score 0):

To get latest changes from `A` (on which `B` is based - assuming as it is not mentioned in question) to `B` is to use [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase). Git rebase will reapply `B` commits on top of current `A` tip.

```
          3---4  branch B
         /
    1---2---fix  branch A
```

will after `git rebase A B` (which translates to two commands `git checkout B` and then `git rebase A`) become:

```
              3'---4'  branch B
             /
    1---2---fix        branch A
```

As fixes PR might be adding more commits in `A` you can apply `git rebase A B` again to reapply commits 3 and 4 on top of the latest tip of `A`.

```
              3'---4'  branch B                      3''---4''  branch B
             /                   ->                 /
    1---2---fix---fix2 branch A      1---2---fix---fix2         branch A
```

etc.

Note `'` and `''` in my diagrams. While contents of commits (changes to source code) will be same, the commits will be *new* commits (have different hashes) as how this works is `git` saves `B` commits to temporary area, resets the starting point of `B` to current tip of `A` and then reapplies previously saved commits (if there are any conflicts on the way you'll have to sort them) - which generates completely new history. So to push rebased `B` to e.g. Github you will need to use --force option to completely rewrite branch history.

See the official manual page I linked in top of my answer for more complicated scenarios (e.g. having some commits of B already integrated to A on the way). If you want to rebase not on `A` tip but specific point in its history see option `--onto`.

I recommend making backup of your current working tree first, before you experiment with rebase.

Comment: I clarified the original Q with a diagram and more details. sorry for not being clear, the question is more about git methodology and best practices than actual